# why is sftp rmdir not working?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to remove a directory with lots of files and folders from my private server space. I'm logging on via SFTP fine; I can access the entire directory no problems; I can even delete individual files with rm. But this would take me forever - so I would really like to just do rmdir on the highest folder that I want to remove. But when I do this, I get

Couldn't remove directory: Failure

Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks very much,
Sam

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In my experience, rmdir prefers to work on an empty directory. If you're trying to delete the directory `foo`, I would do:

```
$rm foo/*
$rmdir foo
```

Comment: SSH'ing to do rm -rf was the obvious answer. I tried rm -rf on SFTP but it couldn't accept -rf, as you pointed out. (The wildcard trick in SFTP didn't work either.) Anyway, thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: That's funny. rm foo/* worked for me in SFTP. Anyway, I'm glad you got it solved!

Comment: Had the same problem and `rm foo/*` wasn't working because `foo/` contained non-empty directories. Luckily `rsync` was allowed too and I created an empty directory _locally_ and then used `rsync -rv --delete empty_local_dir/ host.example.org:/foo/` to remove everything underneath the remote `foo/` directory. Afterwards it was possible to `rmdir foo` via SFTP.

Answer (score 6):

You have not specified, what SFTP client you are using. So I'm assuming OpenSSH SFTP (`sftp`).

Command `rmdir` in OpenSSH SFTP client maps directly to `SSH_FXP_RMDIR` SFTP protocol request. The SFTP spec for version 3 (the one used by OpenSSH) specifically mentions that the `SSH_FXP_RMDIR` operation may fail, *"if the specified directory is not empty"* (though it does not seem to mandate it).

If the directory does not have subdirectories, you can use `rm foo/*` (meaning OpenSSH SFTP command, not shell command) to remove all the files in the directory first. And then use `rmdir`.

For more complex cases, you will need a smarter SFTP client.
Or if you have a shell access, use `rm -r *` in the shell.